# Solving a quadratic equation for ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, quadratics

Suppose we have the equation
\[
\langle a - Ax, B(a - Ax) \rangle \leq t
\]

where $a,x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are invertible. Is there a way I could solve the above to get something like
\[
x \in E
\]
where $E$ is the ellipsoid defined by the quadratic equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u=A^{-1}a$, then:
\begin{align}⟨a−Ax,B(a−Ax)⟩&=(-1)^2⟨A(x-A^{-1}a),BA(x-A^{-1}a)⟩ \\
&=(x-u)^TA^TBA(x-u) \\
&=(x-u)^T\frac 12(A^TBA+(A^TBA)^T)(x-u) \\
&=(x-u)^T\frac 12(A^T(B+B^T)A)(x-u) \\
&=(x-u)^TUDU^T(x-u) \\
&\le t
\end{align}
This is a quadratic form like an ellipsoid, translated by $u$, transformed by the orthogonal matrix $U$, and identified by the diagonal matrix $D$.

Comment: That makes sense. And then $UDU^\top$ is the eigendecomposition of $\frac{1}{2}(A^\top(B + B^\top)A)$?

Comment: Correct @Rahul.

Comment: And then just to follow up, It looks like this entire process should generalize if we replaced $Ax$ by $f(x)$ where $f$ is now an affine transformation of the form $f(x) = Ax + b$ (assuming this new $A$ is also invertible).